# Is it possible to create "extension methods" like in C#, using macro in C++ ?

Tags: c++

I would like to extend the std::string and to add "equals".
So i did the following:

```
#define Equals(str1) compare(str1) == 0
```

and used the following code:

```
if ( str.Equals("hhhhllll") )
```

Which (i assume) compiles to

```
if ( str.compare("hhhhllll") == 0 )
```

And everything compiles great.

Now i want to improve my macro, add brackets to compile to

```
if ( (str.compare("hhhhllll") == 0) )
```

I've tried something like :

```
    #define (str).Equals(str1) (str.compare(str1) == 0)
```

But it won't compile (the macro simply doesn't fit)

How can i achieve it ?

Comment: Is it for syntactic sugar or something specific?

Comment: At first for syntactic sugar but mainly out of curiosity.

Comment: Please go through this link. http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2014/10/15/extension-methods-in-cpp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your macro:

```
#define (str).Equals(str1) (str.compare(str1) == 0)
```

does not fit because it's not in line with macro definition. You can write something like this:

```
#define Equals(str, str1) (str.compare(str1) == 0)
```

but there is no need. All `std::string` instances can be compared with the overloaded `operatror==`.
So that you can write following code:

```
if (str == str1)
```

Using macro definition in C++ is highly unrecommended.

Comment: angor, Thanks you for your answer. But it is not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to figure out if something similar to C# "extension method" is possible in C++ using macros. A workaround like using "str==str1" or "Equals(str,str1)" is nice. But it will be "cool" and "fun" to add something like str.equals(str2) using macros. you said "It's not in line with macro definition" what do you mean by that ?

Comment: @OopsUser getting the same syntactic sugar as in C# won't be possible with macros, unfortunately.

Comment: @OopsUser, I think this [has been discussed](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4174.pdf). Possibly for C++ 17. But not using macros, luckily :)